# A polygon is monotone if there is a line that intersects it in one single connected component

Tags: terminology, definition, computational-geometry

In the following picture

[image]

the first two (top) polygons are [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_polygon), whereas the last two (bottom) polygons are not, with respect to the line $L$. At page $51$ of the book "[Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](http://people.inf.elte.hu/fekete/algoritmusok_msc/terinfo_geom/konyvek/Computational%20Geometry%20-%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications,%203rd%20Ed.pdf)" (3rd edition) by Berg et al., the authors state

> Since $P$ is not monotone, there is a horizontal line $\ell$ that intersects $P$ in more than one **connected component**.

It is not clear to me what a connected component is, in this context, even though I am aware of [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of graphs.

What is a formal definition of a "connected component" in this context? Why "connected"? What is connected? What is an example of a non-connected component? What are the components? Components of what?

Comment: If you want to learn about connectedness in a rigorous manner then you can consult a topology book, I recommend Munkres "Topology".

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the pictures, what you probably want is for **every** line to intersect the polygon in a single connected component.

An attempt at informal formality:

Connected subset: A set that cannot be split into two disjoint, nonempty open sets.

Connected component: a connected subset that is maximal, i.e. is not contained in any larger connected subset. This is a largest possible connected chunk, or component, of the space. It turns out that any space splits into a unique collection of connected components. For example: a point is a connected subset of an interval, but all of the points in the interval sit inside the interval, which is connected itself, so the interval is the only connected component of itself.

Why connected: If you can split your subset into several disjoint, nonempty open pieces, those pieces are not connected but just sitting next to each other. Examples are a single point or an interval.

Non-connected component: There is no such definition. For an example of a disconnected subset, consider two separate points on the polygon, or two edges that aren't touching.

Comment: Yes, I more or less had already understood that. I am looking for a more formal and precise definition. If you could address my specific questions, it would also be helpful.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't sure how much you had understood. If you haven't studied any point-set topology you may need to do a fair bit of reading to get the formal definition. Do you know about open sets?

Comment: If you address my specific questions (in a less formal way), maybe that's enough.

Comment: So, in the picture above, the (connected) subsets are line segments, points, polygons, or what?

Comment: For the purposes of the definition, you are considering connected components of the intersection of the polygon and a line. The connected components of this intersection may consists of points and line segments.